# Failure of a simple stat mech simulation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, computational-physics

so I did a simple simulation that I thought would yield a Boltzmann distribution, but it failed to, and I was wondering if anyone has insight into why it failed.

Ok, so I had a simple discrete system of $N$ energy levels, $E_j=j \epsilon, j=1...N$.  Each of these energy levels was given a (initially random) occupation of $o_j$ "particles".  Thus the total number of particles is $\sum_j o_j$, and the total energy is $\sum_j o_j E_j = \epsilon \sum_j o_j j$.

Then, for a large number of iterations, I altered the occupancies in a way that preserved the energy and number of particles.  I tried a number of different "alteration schemes"; for example, one scheme involved picking a random k, and if $o_k>=2$, I kicked one of the particles down to $o_{k-1}$ and one up to $o_{k+1}$.

My hope was that these iterations would cause the state of the system to wander about on the "constant energy surface", and would, in great likelihood, wind up in a Boltzmann distribution, $\log o_k \propto -k$.  But I wasn't seeing that at all.

Does anyone know why these kinds of iterations don't lead me to the Boltzmann distribution?  All I can think of is that there is something special about the iterations I'm doing that keeps the state of the system in some "subgroup" of the constant-energy surface, and I'm not properly "wandering" in phase space.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description what specific algorithms you're using, but I'll give it a shot.

Given an arbitrary initial distribution, a system will relax to a Boltzmann distribution if the system is ergodic. The vast majority of Hamiltonian systems are not. Without having a clear picture of your hand-added mixing mechanism, there's no guarantee that the result there will generate ergodicity. You're probably stuck in some subspace of all available spaces.

Comment: @gatsu, it sounds you are talking about something like a canonical ensemble, where the system exchanges energy with an infinite heat reservoir.  My toy system conserves energy perfectly: it's a micro-canonical ensemble.

Comment: @webb, this seems likely.  And disappointing...  Do you know of any simple toy models in this vein which are ergodic?  Obviously, if I simulated e.g. an interacting 2-d gas, I no doubt would end up with Maxwell-Boltzmann distributed particles, but do you know of any simpler systems?

Comment: I don't think that a system like this will (even with ergodicity) necessarily end up with the Boltzmann distribution.  To get this, you would need to obey a principle of "detailed balance" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance).  Detailed balance requires that the rates of transitions must be related to the energies of the states - which is not true in your simple model.

Comment: @user42541: no I genuinely made a mistake, I prefered deleting my unnecessary comments

Comment: AJK may have a point about Detailed Balance. However, you don't need ncessarily energy related transition rates to get it. The only point is that you need to make sure that every move can be reversed just after it just happened and I don't think that's the case with the algorithm you use. By moving k to k+1 and k-1 (to conserve total energy), it is then impossible to reverse it by picking, say, the particule that went to k-1 is it? What you are doing is a microcanonical Monte Carlo simulation and it is not known for being easy...

Comment: I see two possible choices: 1) generating many (really many) initial conditions and do statistics on these guys; that should do the job 2) the "trick" that people use is to actually run a canonical MC simulation with a temperature tuned so as to be close to a target fixed energy and since your energies are discrete, only keep those accepted configurations that have the energy you want

Answer (score 1):

Your simple transition model doesn't have any energies in it;  $j$ (or $\epsilon j$) is acting as a spatial coordinate and not an energy coordinate.  The net effect of this rule is to have the particles diffuse around the sites without any bias towards one or another.

A common way to achieve detailed balance is through the [Metropolis-Hastings algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm), which in short is:

1. pick a move,
2. (a) if the move decreases the system energy, accept it,
3. (b) if not, accept the move with probability $p_{accept}=e^{-\Delta E/kT}$

The main thing that you need to worry about, in order to achieve detailed balance, is that your method for "picking a move" have the property that the rate of transitions from state $S \rightarrow S'$ is the same as the probability of picking the converse.  The only thing that seems problematic to me are the boundary conditions at $j=1,N$; I'd alleviate this by just adoption periodic boundary conditions in the $j$ coordinate, i.e. allow jumps from $j=1$ to $j=N$ and vice versa, but there's probably another way to handle the edges as well.

My main thought that might get at what you are trying to do would be to allow for fluctuations in the number of particles, i.e. allow transitions where, given a particle in state $j$ it can change into a pair of particles with states $m,n$ ($m+n=j$) and vice versa.  You'd still need to do a Metropolis type of update, but with the energy being controlled by a chemical potential.